# ms access percentage calculation on form

Tags: ms-access, macros

I have 3 text boxes on a form, named `CboNetCost` and `TxtMargin` and `TxtPrice`.

`TxtMargin` has format property as percentage, `CboNetCost` and `TxtPrice` have format property as currency.

I need to increase the value of `CboNetCost` by whatever percentage value I have in `TxtMargin`, and place the answer in `TxtPrice`.

So just to clarify, here's an example, lets say I have ($10.00) in `CboNetCost`, and I select the `TxtMargin` and write 10% value in it, the `TxtPrice` would be $11.00.

I tried adding after update event to the `txtMargin` with this macro
[click to see image of macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyQfg.png)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: are you familiar with using VBA rather than the macro builder in Access?

Comment: yes im a little familiar with VBA but im new to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression as `ControlSource` for *TxtPrice*:

```
=Val(Nz(CboNetCost))*(1+Nz(TxtMargin, 0))
```

To remove parenthesis and minus sign:

```
=Abs(Val(Replace(Replace(Nz(CboNetCost),")",""),"(","")))*(1+Nz(TxtMargin, 0))
```

Comment: its working and thank you very much there's only one thing tho im really sorry i forgot to mention the cost is in paranthisis its negative, i need the answer to be in positive plus normal without parenthesis is there a way for that ?

Comment: You can use `Replace` for this - and `Abs` - see edit.

Comment: ur a genius my friend thanks loadz dono how to thank you it worked !!! how can i add reputation to u lol :S it seems i don't have enough reputation to vote it up

Comment: So nice. Thank you for the kind words.